# How to do Left Join on LINQ using Lambda Query Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

Here on my example, what I am trying to do here is do a left join using LINQ with Lambda Query Syntax. But I always get an Inner Join results. Here is my sample data:

```
        Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
        Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
        Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
        Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

        Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = "terry" };
        Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = "terry" };
        Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = "charlotte" };
        Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = "terry" };
        Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = "magnus" };
```

And here's my declaration on my List:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };
```

Now here's my LINQ Query which I want is a Left Join:

```
var query1 = people.Join(pets, oP => oP.FirstName.ToLower(), oPe => oPe.Owner.ToLower(), 
            (peeps, peets)
            => new 
            {
                PersonFirstName = peeps.FirstName,
                PersonLastName = peeps.LastName,
                DogName = peets?.Name ?? string.Empty
            });
```

But instead I receive an Inner Join results:

[image]

I am missing

> Arlene

that is supposedly part of the result. I think I am missing something on my LINQ Query.

Comment: Not technically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq.  That post has the answer for doing a left outer join using LINQ query syntax, but I think OP is asking for how to do it using LINQ fluent/method syntax.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have that code already, but I want to create it using LINQ Fluent.

Comment: Try this:

            var query = people.GroupJoin(
                    pets,
                    person => person.FirstName.ToUpper(),
                    pet => pet.Owner.ToUpper(),
                    (x, y) => new {Person = x, Pets = y})
                .SelectMany(
                    x => x.Pets.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (x, y) => new {Person = x.Person, Pet = y});

            foreach (var i in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i.Person.FirstName}: {i.Pet?.Name}");
            }

Comment: Uggh... poor formatting in comments.

Comment: It works! @Jon I hope I can mark it as an answer!

Comment: Great!  It's cool.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I will re-open this, and put it as your answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: I already voted it to re-open it. Waiting for it to re-open.